# How to use css stylesheet on jinja2 template?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    {%block title%}
    {%endblock%}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', 
filename='css/main.css')}}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {%block body%}

    {%endblock%}
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this but there is just no css styles that can be seen on my web page. It doesn't link to css file. I tried href="../static/css/style.css" and also tried replacing my href to src, but it still has the same result, no css style that can be seen.

css path is static/css/main.css

Comment: Jinja itself doesn't provide anything called url_for. Are you using Flask, maybe? Do you get an error? "Just doesn't work" isn't enough.

Comment: I am using Flask, I already edited the post to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

try ctrl+Shift+R to refresh the browser for chrome browser

Comment: nope. I didn't encounter any error. Everything works fine except that there's not one styling shown